# Adding color to histogram using ggplot and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help adding color to the two histograms produced using ggplot and facet_wrap

What am I missing:

```
ObesityDataSet_raw_and_data_sinthetic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Height)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 14)+
  facet_wrap(~Gender)
```

It would look like this

[image: Need]

Comment: `aes(x=Height, color=Gender, fill=Gender)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add color to the histograms in ggplot and facet_wrap, you can use the fill argument in the geom_histogram function to specify the color for each histogram. Here's an example code:

```
ObesityDataSet_raw_and_data_sinthetic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Height, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 14, alpha=0.5, position = "identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to manually specify the colours of the histogram add the last line to Ilia Tetin's code:

```
ObesityDataSet_raw_and_data_sinthetic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Height, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 14, alpha=0.5, position = "identity")+
  facet_wrap(~Gender) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```